# Tested Sql connection via Server Explorer but will not Connect at runtime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2019

The issue at hand: Cannot connect to my sql server database with a connection string that works with the server explorers connection tools but does not work with my WPF application.

I am connecting to a sql server "US06S-SQLSRV" at port 49278, database name is "Solutions". I have created an application that needs to connect to this server but there is concern that the server may move in the future so I am trying to dynamically change this string for future use.

This is the connection string that is generated from the connection tool:
`Data Source=US06S-SQLSRV,49278;Initial Catalog=Solutions;Integrated Security=True`

I have copied this string into my App.Config file and I try to test the connection after the user logs in as follows:

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
<add name ="DatabaseConnStringSO"
         connectionString ="Data Source=US06S-SQLSRV,49278;Initial Catalog=Solutions;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

DatabaseHelper.CS

```
public static string sql;
public static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
public static SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
public static SqlDataReader reader;
public static SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter;
public static string DataSource = @"US06S-SQLSRV";

public static string GetConnectionStrings(string Name)
        {
            string strConnx = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ToString();

            return strConnx;
        }

public static void OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = GetConnectionStrings("DatabaseConnStringSO");
                    conn.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show("Solutions Database connection successful press 'OK' to proceed.", "Successful connection", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

                }
            }
            //+Environment.NewLine + "Description: " + Exception.Message.ToString()
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Solutions Database ( " + DataSource + " connection unsuccessful, please seak a MFG personnel to assist in addressing this issue via the configuration window."
                   + Environment.NewLine + "Description: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Unsucessful database connnection, error: 100",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

            }
        }
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.)'

Any help at all will be appreciated.

Things I have tried:

1. Hard coding the string into the commands.
2. Allowing the Ports via firewall rules
3. Checking if the server can be reached via Sql Server management studio (it does with both IP address and Server name)
4. Using IP address in the connection string.
5. Create a table adapter with this database (generates a different error when I try to preview the data base in that manner but the queries work from the table designer view).
6. Yes the table adapter is using the same connection string.
7. TCP/IP is enabled on the server
8. Ensured that remote connections are enabled on the server

At the end of the day I want to connect to this database with a dynamic string.

Edited to display further actions:
Powershell result

Test-NetConnection -Port 49278-ComputerName US08S-SQLSRV

- ComputerName     : US06S-SQLSRV
- RemoteAddress    : 173.18.167.19
- RemotePort       : 49278
- InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 2
- SourceAddress    : 173.18.168.193
- TcpTestSucceeded : True

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString` !!!

Comment: @T.S.  That connection string looks fine `Server` is a synonym for `Data Source`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8.   In Powershell run `Test-NetConnection -Port 49278 -ComputerName US06S-SQLSRV` and add the output to the question.

Comment: Check if TCP-IP protocol is enabled inside sql server settings

Comment: @Babbillumpa TCP-IP is enabled otherwise Sql Server Management studio wouldn't have connected

Comment: @Neil Made the change and that was not the cause of the error. I assumed both methods of retrieving the string was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus far it seems that there is a bug with the System.Data.SqlClient library for visual studio 2019. I was able to do this task with the same exact code with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score -1):

Integrated security basically means, use Windows security to log on to a sql server.  You should create a SQL user specifically for accessing it via your program, and create a connection string based on those values.

See [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for details of how to make a connection string for your SQL server.

Comment: Will try this however I have added this computer's user account as a user on the server.

Comment: Tried this and I'm still getting the error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.)'